# Blazor rerendering on HTTP Get Requests

Tags: http, blazor

I have discovered that on every get request (before it is finished) the application rerenders, and then of course rerenders again, when the task is complete. I can recreate that on the standard example from microsoft:

```
@page "/counter"
@inject HttpClient _http
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@if(currentCount > 0)
{
    <div>test</div>
}
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {

        var json = await _http.GetStringAsync(_http.BaseAddress + "trust/hasTrust?CaseID=4");
      
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

before currentCount++ is reached, it is rerendering. Why is that? And how can I stop it?

Thank you,
Manuela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specific to Http Requests: it's generic to any yielding async call.

This code demonstrates what's happening:

```cs
@using System.Diagnostics;
@page "/counter"
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

@{
    Debug.WriteLine($"ComponentX - {Uid} - Rendered");
}

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@if (currentCount > 0)
{
    <div>test</div>
}
@code {
    private Guid Uid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ComponentX - {Uid} - Render Queued");
        return base.ShouldRender();
    }

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        // A fake async call to get some data
        await Task.Yield();
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

You will see:

```
-- Render on navigating to the page
ComponentX - c5a5d727-2ad0-4bda-84ac-6c777b3fd9f8 - Rendered
-- Double render on button click 
-- first on the first Async Yield
ComponentX - c5a5d727-2ad0-4bda-84ac-6c777b3fd9f8 - Render Queued
ComponentX - c5a5d727-2ad0-4bda-84ac-6c777b3fd9f8 - Rendered
-- second on completion of the handler code
ComponentX - c5a5d727-2ad0-4bda-84ac-6c777b3fd9f8 - Render Queued
ComponentX - c5a5d727-2ad0-4bda-84ac-6c777b3fd9f8 - Rendered
```

Why?

`ComponentBase` (which all Razor components inherit from by default) implements `IHandleEvent`. The Renderer calls this on every UI generated event.

It looks like this:

```cs
    async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
    {
        var uiTask = item.InvokeAsync(obj);

        await this.CheckIfShouldRunStateHasChanged(uiTask);

        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected async Task<bool> CheckIfShouldRunStateHasChanged(Task task)
    {
        var isCompleted = task.IsCompleted || task.IsCanceled;

        if (!isCompleted)
        {
            this.StateHasChanged();
            await task;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

You can override the handler like this:

```cs
Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
{
    var uiTask = item.InvokeAsync(obj);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

At which point you become responsible for calling `StateHasChanged` when you need to refresh the UI.

```cs
private async Task IncrementCount()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    currentCount++;
    // need to refresh to update the counter display
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

For a single render at the completion of the handler you can implement:

```cs
Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
{
    var uiTask = item.InvokeAsync(obj);
    this.StateHasChanged();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Note that this overrides ALL UI events including component callbacks and binds in the component where you implement it.  You can't be choosy!

You can also use the `ComponentBase` method `ShouldRender()` to control rendering.

You can see it being called in `StateHasChanged`:

```cs
    protected void StateHasChanged()
    {
        if (_hasPendingQueuedRender)
            return;

        if (_hasNeverRendered || ShouldRender() || _renderHandle.IsRenderingOnMetadataUpdate)
        {
            _hasPendingQueuedRender = true;

            try
            {
                _renderHandle.Render(_renderFragment);
            }
            catch
            {
                _hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the following code supresses the first render:

```cs
@page "/counter"
@using System.Diagnostics;
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

@{
    Debug.WriteLine($"ComponentX - {Uid} - Rendered");
}

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private Guid Uid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private bool _shouldIReallyRender = true;

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        if (_shouldIReallyRender)
            Debug.WriteLine($"ComponentX - {Uid} - Render Queued");
        else
            Debug.WriteLine($"ComponentX - {Uid} - Render Suppressed");

        return _shouldIReallyRender;
    }

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        _shouldIReallyRender = false;
        await Task.Yield();
        _shouldIReallyRender = true;
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Which gives you this:

```
-- The initial navigation
ComponentX - d7b0507e-b0c5-46d4-a208-fc5848759a5e - Rendered
-- the Yield render supressed
ComponentX - d7b0507e-b0c5-46d4-a208-fc5848759a5e - Render Suppressed
-- the final render on completion of the handler
ComponentX - d7b0507e-b0c5-46d4-a208-fc5848759a5e - Render Queued
ComponentX - d7b0507e-b0c5-46d4-a208-fc5848759a5e - Rendered
```

Or you can restructure your code to handle the double render as suggested in @HH's answer.

Comment: This is a great answer, but if you added something about how you can prevent unwanted renders by returning false from ShouldRender, it would round it off nicely I think.

Comment: @MisterMagoo - good point.  I had forgotten about that.  I've added it some demo code.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I am a little confused why it sees the need to rerender pior to an await. What changes in the UI is it expecting to have in the middle of a Task?? When would that ever make sense?

Comment: It doesn't render prior to the await, it renders on the yield by the await.  No yield, no intermediate render,  There are many user cases.  You've changed a filter on a list and it takes a while to reload, so you show a "Loading new Data" while the task completes rather than the old data.