# Why doesn't StateHasChanged() always invoke OnAfterRenderAsync?

Tags: c#, blazor

The following function is called from two different places in my code:

```
public void SetProperty(ComponentBase caller, string PropertyName, object PropertyValue, bool SaveChanges = true)

{

    try

    {

        var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName);

        if (prop != null)

        {

            this.Caller = caller.GetType().Name;

            prop.SetValue(this, PropertyValue);

            if (SaveChanges)

            {

                this.SaveChanges();

            }

            StateHasChanged();

        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

    }

}
```

In one part of the codebase, I call the above function four times:

```
AppState.SetProperty(this, "SelectedInvestmentId", investmentId, true);
AppState.SetProperty(this, "CurrentEntityType", "Investment", false);
AppState.SetProperty(this, "CurrentEntityId", investmentId, false);
AppState.SetProperty(this, "CurrentEntityName", selectedModel.InvestmentName, false);
```

In the second part of the codebase, I do the exact same thing:

```
AppState.SetProperty(this, "SelectedInvestmentId", investmentId, true);
AppState.SetProperty(this, "CurrentEntityType", "Investment", false);
AppState.SetProperty(this, "CurrentEntityId", investmentId, false);
AppState.SetProperty(this, "CurrentEntityName", workingModel.InvestmentName, false);
```

The problem I'm having is that when I call the SetProperty function in the first part of the codebase, StateHasChanged() gets hit four times, but only invokes OnAfterRenderAsync once.

In the second part of the codebase, I call the SetProperty function four times and it executes OnAfterRenderAsync four times as well.

Why is the behavior of StateHasChanged different despite being the same code?

Comment: There's an explanation, but first are you really calling the second set as you've show straight after each other?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you change a value to itself, then there is no need to rerender and `OnAfterRerender` is only called after rerender, as the name also suggests. See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.onafterrenderasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: I'm still seeing the same behavior even when all the values for the properties I'm setting are the exact same.

Comment: @RandomUsername the real test is trying to set different data. Is the behavior changed then?

Comment: Same behavior even when the data is different.

Answer (score 0):

**Calling `StateHasChanged` doesn't render the component**.

It queues a `RenderFragment` on the Render Queue.  When that queue gets serviced by the Renderer depends on when it gets thread time.

If your code doesn't yield between calls to `StateHasChanged`, you can call it as many times as you like, there will only be one render [and one call to `OnAfterRender`] after the sync code block completes.

You can use this method in a component to make sure the UI updates when you want it to.

```cs
    // Calls StateHasChanged and then yields 
    // This gives the Renderer running on the Synchronisation Context some thread time 
    // to service the Render Queue and update the UI
    private async Task UpdateUI()
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Yield();
    }
```

There's a recent answer of mine here that provides a more detailed explanation of rendering - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76545126/13065781

Comment: The thing is the same exact code is being executed in two different parts of the codebase. StateHasChanged gets called four times in both cases, but OnAfterRenderAsync gets called four times in one of the cases and once in the other case.

Comment: Drop `await Task.Yield();` in between each call in the other case and report back.  Also put some `Debug.WriteLine` code [as shown in the linked article] into the components to see the sequence of events.   Don't take this the wrong way, but there's something missing in the info you're providing: you may think it's irrelevant, but it isn't :-)

Comment: Also where exactly is `SetProperty(...)`